# SwiftUI - Creating a Star Rating View with decimal point fillable foreground colour in

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to develop a star rating view using SwiftUI. I have a maximum of 5 stars, and the tricky part is that I need to fill 4.7 stars. So the last star should only fill up 70% of its foreground color.

Below is the code that I have done so far

```
import SwiftUI
 
struct AverageStarsView: View {
    @Binding var rating: Double
    
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            StarView()
        }
        .frame(maxHeight: 16)
    }
}
 
struct AverageStarsView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        AverageStarsView(rating: .constant(4.7))
    }
}
```

```
struct StarView: View {
    private var fillColor = .yellow
    private var emptyColor = .grey
 
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if let starImage =  UIImage(named: "icon-star", in: .sharedResources, compatibleWith: nil) {
                Image(uiImage: starImage)
                    .resizable()
                    .renderingMode(.template)
                    .foregroundColor(emptyColor)                    
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            }
        }
    }
    
}
 
struct StarView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        StarView()
    }
}
```

How can fill only 70% of the star view.
I can't use .overlay because I need to support iOS 14.

[Sample view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PNcb.png)

Comment: `overlay` is available from iOS 13, you can use it on iOS 14 as well. See the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/menustyleconfiguration/content/overlay(_:alignment:)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `.mask()` modifier that will create a mask of your view with a given view. Here is what you can achieve for a single star:

```swift
struct StarView: View {
    var fillValue: Double
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Rectangle()
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.orange)
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width * fillValue)
            }
        }
        .mask(
            Image(systemName: "star.fill")
                .resizable()
        )
        .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
    }
}
```

Here is the result with the `fillValue` set to 0.7:

[image]

You can then stack them into an `HStack` and make a quick calculation to know the fill value of the last star to make your five stars rating component.

Make sure to use `.mask()` and not `.mask { }` as the last one require iOS 15.0 to be used.